# UWP XAML ScrollViewer scrolling with arrow keys

Tags: image, keyboard, uwp-xaml, scrollviewer

I have a simple code in XAML and the mainpage:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Image Source="Assets/skyline.jpg" KeyDown="Image_KeyDown">

        </Image>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

When I start the programm now, i can scroll with my touchpad, but not with the arrow keys on the keyboard. Why is it like this and how can I change this behaviour? I'm asking this question because I have a much more complex example, where it just works (of course, that example is not only an image). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ScrollViewer` responds to unhandled keyboard events that bubble up from its content.  In your example you're not seeing keyboarding scroll because neither the `Image` nor the `ScrollViewer` are focusable which means there won't be any keyboard events that bubble up to or originate from the `ScrollViewer`.  `Image` derives from `FrameworkElement` which doesn't have the concept of focus.  ScrollViewer *could* receive focus.  But, by default, it doesn't because its default control style has `IsTabStop = "False"`.

The simple solution here is to set `IsTabStop = "True"` on the `ScrollViewer`.  Now that its focusable you will start seeing around the `ScrollViewer` the thick focus rect automatically drawn by the system.  You can disable that by also setting the `UseSystemFocusVisuals="False"`.

In markup...

```xml
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer"
              IsTabStop="True" UseSystemFocusVisuals="False"
              ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Source="Assets/skyline.jpg">
    </Image>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Note**: This is only necessary because there isn't anything in the content that could receive focus.  In more complex scenarios you'll often have something in the ScrollViewer that can be focused (e.g. a 'foo' Button).  In those scenarios scrolling happens via keyboarding as you'd expect because some 'foo' has focus.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. It works splendidly!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ChangeView` method of `ScrollViewer` to scroll in `Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown` event handler.

Please refer to the following code sample:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollviewer" ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Image Source="Assets/skyline.jpg">
        </Image>
</ScrollViewer>
```

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
}
private double horizontalOffset;
private double verticalOffset;
private double step = 5;
private void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("horizontalOffset: "+horizontalOffset+ " verticalOffset: "+verticalOffset);

    switch (args.VirtualKey)
    {

            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left: horizontalOffset = horizontalOffset-step<0 ? 0:horizontalOffset - step; scrollviewer.ChangeView(horizontalOffset,verticalOffset,1);  break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right: horizontalOffset = horizontalOffset+step>scrollviewer.ScrollableWidth?scrollviewer.ScrollableWidth: horizontalOffset + step; scrollviewer.ChangeView(horizontalOffset,verticalOffset,1);break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up: verticalOffset= verticalOffset - step < 0?0:verticalOffset- step; scrollviewer.ChangeView(horizontalOffset,verticalOffset,1);break;
            case Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down: verticalOffset = verticalOffset + step > scrollviewer.ScrollableHeight?scrollviewer.ScrollableHeight:verticalOffset+ step; scrollviewer.ChangeView(horizontalOffset,verticalOffset,1);break;
            default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this one and it works. But the Problem is now, that it even scrolls when i scroll a different UI Element like a List in the UI. I don't know why, but in my other, more complex code, I can even scroll in the scrollviewer with the keys without implementing your solution. Do you know why I have to implement it, when I only have the image in the scrollviewer?